# Using OpenMP in Fortran for common array operations

Tags: parallel-computing, fortran

In Fortran, given arrays A(1000000) and B(1000000), and to compute the sum you simply write:

```
C = A + B
```

However, when I want to implement OpenMP, I have to write an explicit loop:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
DO I = 1, 1000000
C(I) = A(I) + B(I)
END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Is there a better way to do this? I know there is `-parallel` compiler flag but it gives less performance.

Comment: Which compilers do you have access to? I think that `-parallel` is a GCC/gfortran option only.

Comment: I use `ifort` intel compiler.

Comment: Anyways, a flag isn't an option for me. The real code is huge and for some reason the `-parallel` flag gives almost x2 slowdown in my case.

Comment: I stand corrected on which compiler supports that option.

Comment: @Michael -parallel turns on autoparallelization in ifort.  Autoparallelization requires the compiler to prove beyond a shadow of a doubt that this is safe.  That's hard, because the Fortran language standard is a few hundred pages long.  This feature also causes parallelization of loops that might not benefit from it.  In short, it's good to parallelize yourself explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record, you might try putting an OpenMP worksharing region around your array operation syntax:

```
!$omp workshare
C=A+B
```

Don't forget to build with OpenMP enabled (-openmp for the Intel compilers) and to set `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

Comment: Thanks, I was suggested to avoid `WORKSHARE` and I found out why recently. `ifort` translates it to `SINGLE`, I don't know why, but it definitely showed no speedup. So I tried using `gfortran` instead, and it worked fine.

Comment: What `ifort` version are you using?

Comment: I'm using `ifort 14.0.2`

Comment: Array expressions like that were only parallelized by ifort starting in version 15 (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-workshare-constructs-now-parallelize-with-intel-fortran-compiler-150).

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

No, there is not a better way to do this.

## Long answer

`WORKSHARE` is much harder to implement than explicit loop parallelism.  Compilers have been known to do correct but useless (aka "no-op") implementations of `WORKSHARE` that map it to `SINGLE`.  This is correct but obviously provides no performance benefit.

When compilers support `WORKSHARE`, they may do so selectively, e.g. [Intel Fortran 15](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-workshare-constructs-now-parallelize-with-intel-fortran-compiler-150), which means that depending on it may lead to mixed results.

Even when compilers do a good job, in parallel computing in general, you will find that explicit parallelization wins, because the user is required to make good design choices up front and compilers, which are much less intelligent than humans, don't have to make important decisions.