# OpenMP Fortran array operations in target regions

Tags: parallel-computing, fortran, performance, hpc, gpu

I am asking this here for the possibility that someone here is familiar with OpenMP offloading. Is there some other way to parallelise Fortran array operations outside of unrolling the loops of the array operations? I know for multithreading !$omp workshare seems to work but not for target regions.

An example piece of code would be something like this:

```
omp target  
a(:,:) = a(:,:) + b(:,:)   
omp end target
```

Which can be done by unrolling the loop:

```
omp teams distribute parallel do   
do i=1,10;   
  do j=1,10  
    a(i,j) = a(i,j) + b(i,j)   
  end do;   
end do;  
omp end teams distribute parallel do
```

And this parallizes nicely. I would want to avoid unrolling all the array operations but that seems to be necessary

Comment: What do you mean by target regions. Could you provide a minimal working example of a loop that you want to parallelize?

Comment: @ToukoPuro Please edit the original question.

Comment: You're probably better asking this in Stackoverflow

Comment: Duplicate of https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/using-openmp-in-fortran-for-common-array-operations i believe

Comment: Im not sure if you gain anything by further unrolling. Shouldn't one division be enough to make use of multiple cores?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as it concerns OpenMP offload (on GPU) not OpenMP on CPU as in the suggested question